# How to regard foreign currency forward as foreign and domestic bonds on VaR

Tags: fx, value-at-risk, forward

In John Hull's book `Options, Futures and Other Derivatives  9th` `page 507`

We want to calculate the VaR of a `forward contract of a foreign currency` and we should spread forward into two bonds. It's said that

`a forward contract to buy a foreign currency. Suppose the contract matures at time T. It can be regarded as the exchange of a foreign zero-coupon bond maturing at time T for a domestic zero-coupon bond maturing at time T.`

We know that the payment at $T$ is
$$Q_T - K$$
it's easy to understand regarding $K$ as a domestic zero-coupon bond maturing at time $T$ with principle $K.$ But how to regard $Q_T$ as the `foreign zero-coupon?`

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_t$ be the exchange rate from one unit foreign currency to units domestic currency. Moreover, let $K$ be the forward rate set at the contract inception time, which is usually prior to the VaR calculation date $t_0=0$. Then the value at time $t$, where $t_0 \le T \le T$, of the forward contract is given by
\begin{align*}
B_t^d\,\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X_T-K}{B^d_T} \,\big|\, \mathcal{F}_t\right),
\end{align*}
where $B_t^d$ is the domestic money-market account value, $P^f(t, T)$ is the value at time $t$ of the foreign zero coupon bond with maturity $T$, and $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectation operator under the domestic risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}^d$.

As $P^f(t, T)X_t$ and $P^d(t, T)$ are values at time $t$ of domestic tradable assets. the processes $\left\{\frac{P^f(t, T)X_t}{B_t^d}, \, t_0\le t \le T \right\}$ and $\left\{\frac{P^d(t, T)}{B_t^d}, \, t_0\le t \le T \right\}$ are martingales under the domestic risk-neutral measure. Then, the value at $t$ of the forward contract is given by
\begin{align*}
B_t^d\,\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X_T-K}{B^d_T} \,\big|\, \mathcal{F}_t\right) &=
B_t^d\,\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\frac{P^f(T, T)X_T}{B^d_T} -K\frac{P^d(T, T)}{B^d_T}\right) \,\big|\, \mathcal{F}_t\right)\\
&=P^f(t, T)X_t - K P^d(t, T).
\end{align*}
That is, the value of the exchange of certain amount of foreign zero-coupon bond with certain amount of domestic zero-coupon bond.

> Addendum

Here, we provide a mathematical derivation that the process $\left\{\frac{P^f(t, T)X_t}{B_t^d}, \, 0 \le t \le T \right\}$ is a martingale under the domestic risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}^d$.

Let $\mathbb{Q}^f$ be the foreign risk-neutral measure, and $\mathbb{E}^f$ be the corresponding expectation operator. Note that the process $\left\{\frac{P^f(t, T)}{B_t^f}, \, 0 \le t \le T \right\}$ is a martingale under the foreign risk-neutral measure. We denote by $\eta_t$ the Radon–Nikodym derivative 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}^d}{d\mathbb{Q}^f}\big|_t = \frac{B_t^d X_0}{B_t^f X_t}.
\end{align*}
Then, for $0 \le s \le t \le T$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{P^f(t, T)X_t}{B_t^d}\, \big| \, \mathcal{F}_s\right) &= \mathbb{E}^f\left(\frac{\eta_t}{\eta_s}\frac{P^f(t, T)X_t}{B_t^d}\, \big| \, \mathcal{F}_s\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}^f\left(\frac{B_t^d}{B_t^f X_t} \frac{B_s^f X_s}{B_s^d}\frac{P^f(t, T)X_t}{B_t^d}\, \big| \, \mathcal{F}_s\right)\\ 
&=\frac{B_s^f X_s}{B_s^d}\mathbb{E}^f\left(\frac{P^f(t, T)}{B_t^f}\, \big| \, \mathcal{F}_s\right)\\ 
&=\frac{P^f(s, T)X_s}{B_s^d}.
\end{align*}
That is,  $\left\{\frac{P^f(t, T)X_t}{B_t^d}, \, 0 \le t \le T \right\}$ is a martingale under the domestic risk-neutral measure.

Comment: I think under the `domestic risk neutral measure,` $\dfrac{B^fX}{B^d}$ is martingale, thus $\dfrac{P^fX}{B^d}$ must not be martingale.

Comment: @A.Oreo: You are right that $\frac{B_t^f X_t}{B_t^d}$ is a martingale under the domestic risk-neutral measure; however, note that the value at maturity $T$ is $\frac{B_T^f X_T}{B_T^d}$, which is not the form $\frac{X_T}{B_T^d}$ that we are going to consider. Instead, the process $\frac{P^f(t, T) X_t}{B_t^d}$ satisfies our requirement, that is, the value at the forward contract maturity $T$ is $\frac{X_T}{B_T^d}$.

Comment: So, here you no longer use the `domestic risk-neutral measure,` instead, you use the measure $E$ to make $\dfrac{P^fX}{B^d}$ and $\dfrac{1}{B^d}$ martingale? And under this measure does $B_t^d E[\dfrac{1}{B_T^d}]$  still mean the bond price?

Comment: $E$ is not a measure, instead, it is the **expectation operator** under the domestic risk-neutral measure. Then $B_t^dE\left( \frac{1}{B_T^d}\right) = P^d(t, T)$.

Comment: So, the identity $B^d_tE\left(\dfrac{1}{B^d_T}\right) = P^d(t,T)$ only holds under the domestic risk-neutral measure, but $\dfrac{P^fX}{B^d}$ is impossible martingale under the domestic risk-neutral measure.

Comment: See my answer above, both are martingales.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand. The definition of domestic risk-neutral measure is making the $\dfrac{B^fX}{B^d}$(not $\dfrac{P^fX}{B^d}$) martingale, if  $\dfrac{B^fX}{B^d}$ is martingale, $\dfrac{P^fX}{B^d}$ must not be martingale.

Comment: Under the risk-neutral measure, **all tradable** asset price divided by the money-market account value is a martingale. $P^f X$ is domestically tradable.

Comment: how about $B^fX$? It's also domestically tradable.

Comment: Yes. they are both martingales. However, I use $P^fX/B^d$ rather than $B^fX/B^d$ as I want to have $X/B^d$ as the terminal value.

Comment: I think they are impossible both martingale under one measure if there is only one factor.

Comment: Our discussion is long enough. Please ask another question to discuss the martingality.